# How do I get a cookie from user input, and display it on an html element

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm making a website that uses a cookie to get the user's name. When I try to get it to be shown with inner.html, it won't even prompt the user. Here is my code. The area is specific is the function checkCookie()

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var user=getCookie("username");
         if (user != null) {
            document.getElementById("person").innerHTML =
            "Hello " + user + "!";
        } else {
           user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
           if (user != "" && user != null) {
               setCookie("username", user, 30);
           }
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkCookie()">
    <p id="person">anonymous user</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `getCookie` never returns `null`. If the cookie isn't found, it returns an empty string.

Comment: basic debugging: did you check your JS console for errors? Any errors in the code, the entire script block gets killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return "";
```

to:

```
return null;
```

`checkCookie` expects `getCookie` to return `null` when the cookie isn't found. An empty string is not the same as `null`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/de66xqb5/1/)

Comment: I did that, but then it didn't prompt the user, and the p tag said null

Comment: Note that you have to reload the page to see the name, because you don't update the `innerHTML` after prompting.